# Sorting dataframe

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have two dataframes of same dimensions. But as shown I want to order the dataframe `data`such that the `id_num` is ordered in the order of `id_num` of `reference`. The output should look like the dataframe `required`.

How can I do it?

```
reference <- data.frame(id_num=c(206,307,408,506), Event_1=0, Event_2=0)
```

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(id_num=c(506,307,408,206), Event_1=c(1,3,5,7), Event_2=c(2,4,6,8))
```

[image]

```
required <- data.frame(id_num=c(206,307,408,506), Event_1=c(7,3,5,1), Event_2=c(8,4,6,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Here is one option with `data.table` `nm1 <- names(reference)[-1];setDT(reference)[data, (nm1) := mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), on = .(id_num)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
merged <- merge(reference[,"id_num",drop=FALSE],data,by="id_num")
```

Comment: or just `merge(reference["id_num"], data)`